# How to pass a delayed function as argument to another function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm writting a function that receives 3 arguments. The first argument is a function/process to be applied to each element of an array, which is the second argument, and finally, the last argument is the time to delay the first function argument. The way to apply the function is defined in another function which receives a function as first argument, and an array as second argument, that function is curried.

Taking this snipet

```
function a (fn){
  return function (set){
    return set.map(item => ()=> fn(item)).reduce((current,next) => /*some function*/);
  }
}

function b (fn, set, time){
  return a(setTimeout(arg => fn(arg), 1000))(set);
}
```

For instance, `a` could be a sequence. if you call `a` with a function and a set, then the function will be applied to all the items of the set in sequence.

`b` is just (taking the sequence example) the execution of the sequence, but I want to delay the item execution.

I cannot achieve what I've described above and I don't know why. I'm missunderstanding something, but I don't know what.

Could you help me to understand please?

Comment: The return value of `setTimeout()` is not a function; it's a number.

Comment: @Pointy That's true always? If so, how could achieve what I want?

Comment: It is true 100% of the time.  There's no such thing as a "delayed" function; a function is either called or it's not, and when it's called it runs immediately. You could wrap the call to `setTimeout()` in another function, but then the idea of calling the return value from `a()` after the timeout fires would not work.

Comment: Some example input/output would be helpful here.

Comment: You should return a promise from the asynchronous function. Or work with callbacks, but I'd recommend to avoid that, since you're already confusing yourself.

Comment: @Bergi I've already achieved to do it with Promises. The problem is that I've implemented a promises sequencer with failure tolerance, that function receives the function (which returns a Promise) to be applied to each array item. The sequencer works as expected. 

The next step is to make the sequence delaying the execution of each process (because of time limitation, if to process an item is too fast, then you may want to process n items/second) I wanted to reuse the already working sequence function, because I've already implemented a version without reusing the sequence returning a Promise

Comment: So you should make a function that returns a promise for the slowed-down process. Nothing changes about the sequencer. `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise, so you can't use it without promisifying it.